# Google Analytics Unity plugin - No data showing up

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-analytics

I am trying to use the Google Analytics for Unity plugin ([link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/unity/v3/devguide)) to be able to track user statistics. I believe I have everything correctly set up but am not seeing anything on the dashboard or real-time view.
I have set up the Analytics account and property well over 48 hours ago (last weekend) and have included it in my unity project:

[image: Screenshot of my prefab configuration in unity]

My code in unity (called when the player dies):

```
        Debug.Log("Should send data to google analytics now");
            googleAnalytics.LogEvent("game", "death", "something", 0);
            googleAnalytics.LogEvent(new EventHitBuilder()
                            .SetEventCategory("game")
                            .SetEventAction("death")
                            .SetCustomMetric(1, "" + (int) (score * 1000))
                            .SetCustomMetric(2, "" + gameNumber));
```

The logs from my android device:

```
11-06 20:37:37.291  5071  5102 I Unity   :
11-06 20:37:37.308  5071  5102 I Unity   : Killing player (UnityEngine.GameObject)
11-06 20:37:37.308  5071  5102 I Unity   :
11-06 20:37:37.308  5071  5102 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.
cpp Line: 64)
11-06 20:37:37.308  5071  5102 I Unity   :
11-06 20:37:37.308  5071  5102 I Unity   : I was killed
11-06 20:37:37.308  5071  5102 I Unity   :
11-06 20:37:37.308  5071  5102 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.
cpp Line: 64)
11-06 20:37:37.308  5071  5102 I Unity   :
11-06 20:37:37.308  5071  5102 I Unity   : Should send data to google analytics now
11-06 20:37:37.308  5071  5102 I Unity   :
11-06 20:37:37.308  5071  5102 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.
cpp Line: 64)
11-06 20:37:37.308  5071  5102 I Unity   :
11-06 20:37:37.308  5071  5102 I Unity   : Logging event.
11-06 20:37:37.308  5071  5102 I Unity   :
11-06 20:37:37.308  5071  5102 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.
cpp Line: 64)
11-06 20:37:37.308  5071  5102 I Unity   :
11-06 20:37:37.309  5071  5102 I Unity   : Logging event.
11-06 20:37:37.309  5071  5102 I Unity   :
11-06 20:37:37.309  5071  5102 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.
cpp Line: 64)
11-06 20:37:37.309  5071  5102 I Unity   :
11-06 20:37:37.310  5071  5141 V GAV3    : Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
11-06 20:37:37.310  5071  5141 V GAV3    : Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service   PATH: https:  PARAMS: sr=10
80x1776,  ht=1446838657309,  sf=100,  _u=.r33yAAAAAL,  ec=game,  did=GbOCSs,  cid=229fc034-20c1-49ff-96c7-218660d739de,
 ev=0,  av=1.0,  v=1,  an=Stay High,  ul=en-us,  t=event,  tid=UA-xxxxxxx-5 ,  ea=death,  aid=com.yey.stayhigh,  el=some
thing,
11-06 20:37:37.310  5071  5102 I Unity   : Added custom variables to hit.
11-06 20:37:37.310  5071  5102 I Unity   :
11-06 20:37:37.310  5071  5102 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.
cpp Line: 64)
11-06 20:37:37.310  5071  5102 I Unity   :
11-06 20:37:37.312  5071  5102 V GAV3    : Thread[UnityMain,5,main]: Dispatch call queued. Dispatch will run once initia
lization is complete.
11-06 20:37:37.346  5071  5141 V GAV3    : Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
11-06 20:37:37.346  5071  5141 V GAV3    : Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service   PATH: https:  PARAMS: sr=10
80x1776,  ht=1446838657312,  sf=100,  _u=.r3yAAAAABL,  ec=game,  did=GbOCSs,  cid=229fc034-20c1-49ff-96c7-218660d739de,
 ev=0,  cm2=80,  av=1.0,  v=1,  an=Stay High,  ul=en-us,  t=event,  tid=UA-xxxxxxx-5 ,  ea=death,  aid=com.yey.stayhigh,
  cm1=6102,  el=,
```

I have my Analytics project set up as a mobile project as well.
I really don't understand why these hits are not showing up on my dashboard as they do seem to be getting sent. Does anyone have a possible explanation for this? Did I maybe forget about something else?

Comment: Make sure your test device is not blocking ads / analytics calls.